# Necromancer Badge Not Awarded

Tags: support, badges

here is the badge description

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer

and here the question asked Apr 19 '17 and answered answered Feb 17 '18. Score 25 (accepted and upvoted).

[gtrendsR Error: widget$status_code == 200 is not TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488946/gtrendsr-error-widgetstatus-code-200-is-not-true/48842408#48842408)

Any idea why badge has not been awarded?

Thanks

Comment: Score is different from reputation. 1 upvote is a score of 1, but is 10 reputation.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, you 're right, corrected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer has a score of *one*, not 25, which is less than the 5 it needs to be in order to qualify for the badge.